# How to change the (number of) x-axis ticks in a plot.zoo plot? (axis() fails)

Tags: r, xts, zoo

The following time series plot with `plot.zoo()` shows a weird number of (only one) x-axis ticks. How can one convince `plot.zoo()` to show more x-axis ticks?

```
## Create a dummy time series
library(xts)
start <- as.Date("2020-04-01")
end <- as.Date("2021-06-02")
dat <- seq(start, end, length.out = 226)
set.seed(271)
ts <- xts((1:226) + rnorm(226, sd = 1/3), order.by = dat)
plot.zoo(ts) # => only one x-axis tick displayed
```

I tried the usual to change the x-axis, but for some reason (?) `axis()` is not respected here:

```
## Trial
plot.zoo(ts, xaxt = "n")
ticks <- axTicksByTime(index(ts))
labels <- names(ticks)
axis(1, at = ticks, labels = labels) # => no x-axis ticks displayed
```

If you need more details, just let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a version based on standard `plot()`:

```
plot(as.numeric(ts), type = "l", xaxt = "n")
ticks <- axTicksByTime(index(ts), format.labels = "%Y-%m-%d")
labels <- names(ticks)
axis(1, at = ticks, labels = labels)
```

And a somewhat nicer one:

```
plot(as.numeric(ts), type = "l", xaxt = "n", xlab = "", ylab = "ts")
ticks <- axTicksByTime(index(ts), format.labels = "%Y-%m")
labels <- names(ticks)
axis(1, at = ticks, labels = labels, las = 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with the code in the question:

- the code in the question calls `plot.zoo` which is calling the zoo method directly.  In general, code should call the generic and let it dispatch the method rather than calling the method directly. (The main situation where one must call the method directly is when the generic appears in a different package that is not currently loaded; however, that is not the case for `plot` since it is part of base R.)
- `?axTicksByTime` says *This function is written for internal use*
- if you want to use`axTicksByTime` anyways then note that it returns *indexes* into the time vector and not the times themselves.  That is why nothing appeared when the question used the `axis` command.

If you want to use `axTicksByTime` anyways and use it with the zoo method of `plot` then it would be done like this.

```
plot(as.zoo(ts), xaxt = "n")
ticks <- axTicksByTime(ts, format = "%Y %m")
labels <- names(ticks)
axis(1, at = time(ts)[ticks], labels = labels)
```